# Use segue for item selected in table view

Tags: swift, segue

I've looked at other possible solutions here on StackOverflow but don't quite think they apply to my issue or simple I don't understand is the greater possibility.  Here is what I am trying to do.  I have a tableview with sections and items in each section.  I want to segue to a different view controller based on the selection made by the user in the tableview.  I have set up a sample with the following code with segues "report1Segue" and "report2Segue" as an example.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var reportTableView: UITableView!

    let reportGroup = ["Dietary", "Weight", "Sleep", "Meditation", "Fitness"]

    let report = [["Calorie Breakdown", "Net Calories"], ["Last 3 Months"], ["Last 3 Months"],["Last 3 Months"],["Exercises by Type"]]

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return report.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return reportGroup[section]
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "reportSegue" {
            if let reportVC = segue.destination as? Report1ViewController, let indexPath = reportTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

                reportVC.dataToDisplay = report[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return report[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = report[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "report1Segue", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

Any guidance is always greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 5.2**

For fixed data in a `UITableView` you can do it like this:

```
// Hard code your IndexPath references
// This will make the code easier to read in the delegate methods
enum TableIndex {
    static let calorieBreakdown =          IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    static let netCalories =               IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
    static let weightLastThreeMonths =     IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
    static let sleepLastThreeMonths =      IndexPath(row: 0, section: 2)
    static let meditationLastThreeMonths = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 3)
    static let fitnessExercises =          IndexPath(row: 0, section: 4)
}


// Example - perform whatever Segues you actually need
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath {
    case TableIndex.calorieBreakdown:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "report1Segue", sender: self)
    case TableIndex.weightLastThreeMonths, TableIndex.sleepLastThreeMonths:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "report2Segue", sender: self)
    default:
        break
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
    let data = report[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    switch segue.identifier {
    case "report1Segue":
        if let dest = segue.destination as? Report1ViewControler {
            dest.dataToDisplay = data
        }
    case "report2Segue":
        if let dest = segue.destination as? Report2ViewControler {
            dest.dataToDisplay = data
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much for looking at this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what needs to happen here is 1, in your `didSelectRowAt`, you need to figure out what is tapped, So based on how you are displaying the cells, you need to do the same here to find out what cell is tapped. Then based on that selection you will either have a switch case or if else statements that will each call its unique `performSegue` so that based on a cell selection it will go to a different selection.

For your example, you 'selection' is report[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

then if switch or if else 
if will be like

```
if selection == "Last 3 Months" || selection == "Net Calories" {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "report1Segue", sender: nil)
} else if selection == "Calorie Breakdown" {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "report2Segue", sender: nil)
}
```

Hope this helps you out.